# Django sessions behavior

Tags: python, django, session

i am trying to understand how django sessions work so in  my **cart view**  i set a session variable named **cart_id** if  i does not already exists , in my **inspect element storage**  i see the  **session_id** and  i have a value let's say **session_id = 1** ( i am not logged in) now when i login the **session_id**  is  different let's say  **session_id=2**   but   i am still able to retrieve the data from the previous session (1) , i mean   if the session changes i shouldn't be able to do that ,  why  can  i do that ??

can anyone explain to me the session behavior ?

Comment: You could use a different browser or container to mimic a different session.

Comment: @KentShikama so the session changes only if the browser changes ??

Comment: You could also clear cookies on your browser.